# Eclipse Rcp run E4 based code after the whole application has started and the GUI has completely rendered

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

i have an E3/E4 mixed application with compatibility layer. I would like to run E4 based code after the whole application has started and the GUI has completely rendered.

- I tried to use a LifeCycle Manager but all annotations are to early for it.
- I tried it in the ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor but there I have no access to the EModelService or MApplication.
- As a processor extension I tried it too, but this is also too early the same for an Addon in the Application.e4xmi.

Is there maybe a listener or something similar where I can hook my code?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Application Startup Complete event for this.

If you have a Life Cycle class just add a method like the following to the class:

```java
@Optional
@Inject
public void appStartupComplete(@UIEventTopic(UIEvents.UILifeCycle.APP_STARTUP_COMPLETE) final Event event)
{
   ....
}
```

Or you can use the event broker to subscribe to the `UIEvents.UILifeCycle.APP_STARTUP_COMPLETE` event.

Note: `Event` in the above is `org.osgi.service.event.Event` - there are several different `Event` classes so it is easy to get the wrong one.